# rangeslider.js jQuery deferred exception rangeslider is not a function in project but no issues with Codepen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, rangeslider

I am trying to add a Range-slider to my Django project using rangeslider.js. I created a working example in Codepen
https://codepen.io/Slurpgoose/pen/GRRpmpX and everything seems to work fine.

When attempting to initiate the same slider on localhost I keep getting a jQuery deferred exception.

`[Error] TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...$('input[type="range"]').rangeslider...')     (anonymous function) (jquery-3.3.1.js:3827)`

Here I created an example including all of my imports. I have attempted to remove all the imports except for jQuery, and rangeslider and cleared my cache. Unfortunately this did not resolve my issue.

`my script is called strategyBuilder.js`

minimal example of my code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  console.log("loaded");
  $('.slider').rangeslider({
          polyfill: false,
          rangeClass: 'rangeslider',
          disabledClass: 'rangeslider--disabled',
          horizontalClass: 'rangeslider--horizontal',
          fillClass: 'rangeslider__fill',
          handleClass: 'rangeslider__handle',

          onInit: function() {

          },

          onSlide: function(position, value) {

          },

          onSlideEnd: function(position, value) {

          }
      })
})
```

```css
.container {
  margin: 10%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/solid.js"></script>
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/fontawesome.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/10.6.2/bootstrap-slider.js" integrity="sha256-59/apVFrosMLFX2dHZLGvb3nPpu7e0Yx1rsDr1dTRrk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rangeslider.js/2.3.2/rangeslider.js" integrity="sha256-ZhpcIWx8GPtl1VEkyV22X7GHSzX1NCdp6BvbXMDHI/g=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
  <script src="{% static 'js/strategyBuilder.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/10.6.2/css/bootstrap-slider.css" integrity="sha256-+bpMasWDxDlsVpNW3oZlL7L4RacwsP70u2fZt6Rxrmc=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rangeslider.js/2.3.2/rangeslider.css" integrity="sha256-jJApoDvazb6sRGbc3gE+wdEAE0cE0H1Ag3k1qCada9c=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome-animation/0.2.1/font-awesome-animation.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/theme.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/strategyBuilder.css' %}">

<div class="container">
<input class="slider"
    type="range"
    min="1"                    // default 0
    max="100"                // default 100
    step="5"                   // default 1
    value="300"                 // default min + (max-min)/2
    data-orientation="horizontal" // default horizontal
>
</div>
```

Comment: Everything works fine in the snippet...

Comment: @Rojo I know thats the problem I am facing. I am looking for any ideas debugging

Comment: Just use `console.log(String);`

Comment: @Rojo jquery is loaded, and I am able to retrieve to do let item = $('.slider'); console.log($(item).attr('class'). I even tried creating a local version .rangeslider.js and added a console to the file. it is consoled first so in theory its loaded before this the slider is initialized.

Comment: That's not what I said... `console.log` is a function already included in JS, no need to add it...

Comment: @Rojo lol my post literally uses a console.log... I added a console.log to a file that I imported sorry if that wasn't clear. the file that I added it to was the local copy of the cdn link. I did so was to confirm that it was imported prior to my js file which it was. my comment also stated that jquery is loaded before this function is called. As well jquery is able to find the input element because I can log the attributes for the input elements using jquery attr selector prior to the function being called. `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rangeslider.js/2.3.2/rangeslider.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using Django template extend at the top of my html file. As a result I was importing all imports from a file called base.html containing header/footer etc...

I had also had jQuery included in that file. removing it fixed my issue

will leave my question up in case for some reason someone has this problem